# How to find jUnit tests in a Java project?

Tags: java, junit, grep

I have a Java project with a lot of classes. Now I want to get a list with all jUnit tests. My idea was to use grep for that.

So I navigated to the root folder, and use the following command:

```
grep junit -R ./ > output.txt
```

But obviously this isn't correct. So my question is. How is the correct command? And are there ways that are more easier to find jUnit tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd want:

```
grep -r junit *
```

But you need to be a little careful with that, as it'll go through all files, include jars.

Better to use `find` or [`ack`](http://betterthangrep.com/):

```
ack --java -cl '@Test' # Print filenames with, and # occurences of, @Test annotations
```

Or more boringly:

```
find . -name *.java | xargs grep junit
ack --java junit # Or, more accurately:
ack --java 'import\s.*?junit.*'
```

(If you're not using ack, for some stuff, it's just awesome.)

Answer (score 4):

```
find . -name *.java | egrep -R @Test . | cut -f1 -d" " | cut -f1 -d: > _1
```

If you've got junit 3 ones too, you could then run:

```
find . -name *Test.java >> _1
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain the first line a little bit?

Comment: @Roflcoptr It's grepping for `@Test` annotations and pulling the filename out. Doesn't work on OSX, though, get repeated filenames w/ no contextual info. One reason I like `ack` :)

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -name "*.java" | xargs grep -il "junit"
```

In english:
Starting at the current directory, find all files that end in ".java".
For each file found, do a case-insensitive search for "junit".
If "junit" is found, print only the file name.

Answer (score 0):

I would `grep` for "`extends TestCase`" - results likely are going to be more reliable

**Any class that extends TestCase is automatically a JUnit class.**

Depending on whether you use jUnit 3 or 4 you may not have `@Test` annotations

Comment: Yes, but JUnit4 tests don't extend TestCase

Comment: @MatthewFarwell, really? can you post a reference confirming this? I was under impression that all jUnit tests (by definition) `extend TestCase`

Comment: TestCase is part of JUnit3, it still works with JUnit4, but isn't necessary. Try it.